# Spring Boot - Load a Component on Management Context

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-jetty

In order to control the amount of threads on the jetty main embedded server I load a `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` using the `@Component` annotation. Im using a different port for the management context and so it seems that a different jetty instance is executed for that port. How can I do the same process for that port or Jetty instance?

Regards

Bruno

Comment: It is the same Jetty instance, just a different connector.

Comment: But the component only calls the `public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container)` once. Shoudlnt it be called twice? one for each connector?

Comment: No because there is only a single container with 2 connectors...

Comment: I have this configuration `@Override
public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
 if (container instanceof JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
  final InstrumentedQueuedThreadPool threadPool =
   new InstrumentedQueuedThreadPool(metricRegistry, jettyConfiguration.getMaxThreads(),
    jettyConfiguration.getMinThreads(), jettyConfiguration.getIdleTimeout(),
    new BlockingArrayQueue<>(jettyConfiguration.getQueuedRequests()));
  }
}` but it only affects the main connector. How can I change the management connector?

Comment: The main point here is that I configure this `ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer ` and only the main connector is changed.. How can I change the management connector?

Comment: After some digging I found out that the management side of spring boot is supported by a different application context (every time you put the management on a different port this context is created) which is a child from the main application context. So the actual question is how can I create a `ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer ` bean that is injected in both contexts? Please keep in mind that the child context for management is automatically created.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out how to solve my issue.

Using the application properties

`server.jetty.acceptors`
`server.jetty.selectors`

I can control the amount of threads on both ports. It is not very customisable but it gets the job done. For the main service port, configuring with a `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` will override these configurations.

Regards